# RXJS calling a JSON file that updates every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular-services, angular-http

I have a JSON file with GPS coordinates. This file updates every 30 seconds subsequently updating the latitude and longitude coordinates. I currently have a service grabbing the link to my API but whenever the API reloads after 30 seconds it causes an error in mine console saying the coordinates haven't been called.

**This is how I'm calling the link to my API.**

```
getFirstDevice() {
if (! this.data) {
  return this._http.get(this.busFeed).pipe(
    map((data: Response) => this.data  = data),
    tap(data => console.log('Server info: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
   );
} else {
  return this.data;
}}
```

I'd imagine i need to use a different operator than map in this instance? Absolutely any suggestions would be amazing.

Comment: I think the error comes from backend, try to get coodinated every minute.

Comment: Please, show exact error. Also, can you tell where does the error occur, in the code you've shown or it originates from other place?

Comment: map _is_ the wrong operator, you're not performing a mapping (i.e. transform emitted data into something else), but a side-effect (setting `this.data`), it should be `.tap` as well.